# CNTK Error on HelloWorld LR

Tags: windows, cntk

I'm attempting to use CNTK v2 (CNTK version 2.0 Beta 12). Everything installs properly however when I attempt to start the [HelloWorld](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-CNTK-on-Windows#test-of-cntk-build-functionality) Logistic Regression tutorial

`cntk configFile=lr_bs.cntk makeMode=false`

I receive a R6030 - CRT not initialized error.

Comment: What version of Windows do you use?  Do get the same result on Windows 10?  We have had reports of this error for Windows 7 users.

Comment: Win 7 SP1  64 bit with KB 2952664

Comment: Is it only this BrainScript example? Can you try others. Also, let us know if you have problems with the examples / tutorials in the python environment.

Comment: This is on every example. Running cntk with no arguments yields the same errors.

Comment: Just to be clear. You are having this problem even with the python tutorials? How did you run CNTK with no arguments in python env

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am a Windows 7 user and the python tutorials seem fine. Did you solve this problem already?

Answer (score 0):

[These steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ecfyw6c.aspx) can sometimes resolve this issue.